# Why doesn't anacron run the tasks scheduled?

Tags: fedora, cron, anacron

I've set `anacron` to run several tasks, but it seems to fail due to some sort of weird permissions error.

This is my `anacrontab`:

```bsh
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1   5   cron.daily      nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7   25  cron.weekly     nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45 cron.monthly        nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly

@daily  1   bashrc.daily    rsync -aAX $HOME/.bashrc /run/media/MYUSER/samsung/home/MYUSER/.bashrc
@daily  1   bash_aliases.daily  rsync -aAX $HOME/.bash_aliases /run/media/MYUSER/samsung/home/MYUSER/.bash_aliases
@daily  5   variety.daily   rsync -aAX $HOME/.config/variety/ /run/media/MYUSER/samsung/home/MYUSER/.config/variety/
@daily  3   testfile.daily  rsync -aAX $HOME/Documents/flag.hs /run/media/MYUSER/samsung/flag.hs
@weekly 5   st_apps.daily   rsync -aAX $HOME/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/ /run/media/MYUSER/samsung/home/MYUSER/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/
@weekly 15  st_ud.daily rsync -aAX $HOME/.local/share/Steam/userdata/ /run/media/MYUSER/samsung/home/MYUSER/.local/share/Steam/userdata/
@weekly 1   anacrontab.weekly   rsync -aAX /etc/anacrontab /run/media/MYUSER/samsung/home/anacrontab
```

This is the output of `journalctl  -b --no-pager --catalog | grep anacron`

```bsh
jan. 14 00:02:09 MYPC anacron[73073]: Anacron started on 2022-01-14
jan. 14 00:02:09 MYPC anacron[73073]: Can't open timestamp file for job cron.daily: Permission denied
jan. 14 00:02:09 MYPC anacron[73073]: Aborted
jan. 14 00:02:42 MYPC sudo[73113]:     MYUSER : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/MYUSER ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/dd bs=4k of=/etc/anacrontab
jan. 14 00:02:50 MYPC sudo[73124]:     MYUSER : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/MYUSER ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/dd bs=4k of=/etc/anacrontab
```

Could someone *please* prod me in the right direction?

System: Fedora 35

Comment: Does this help: https://superuser.com/questions/1270943/anacron-cron-daily-not-running-my-scripts

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. All the permissions on folders are as they should be, but running `anacron -fnd` with root privilege works.

Comment: What does `ls -al /etc/cron.daily` return?

Comment: brave-browser, brave-key-updater, and rpm. All of which seem to contain scripts.

Comment: It's unclear who's running the jobs that you show. Is it root? How and from where are you invoking `anacron`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `anacron` worked earlier but doesn't work any more, so I decided to take a different approach. To be able to run it without escalated privileges, you will need to do as follows:

1. Create an `.anacron` folder in your home dir and two subdirs (`etc` and `spool`) by using the command `mkdir -p ~/.anacron/{etc,spool}`.
2. Create a new file in the `etc` dir by running `touch $HOME/.anacron/etc/anacrontab` with contents similar to the original `/etc/anacrontab`. E.g.:

```bsh
# Personal anacrontab

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
@daily  1   bashrc.daily    rsync -aAXr $HOME/.bashrc /run/media/myuser/samsung/home/myuser/.bashrc
@daily  1   bash_aliases.daily  rsync -aAXr $HOME/.bash_aliases /run/media/myuser/samsung/home/myuser/.bash_aliases
```

3. In the terminal, enter `crontab -e` and add the following:

```bsh
@hourly /usr/sbin/anacron -s -t $HOME/.anacron/etc/anacrontab -S $HOME/.anacron/spool
```

You can test wait for cron to execute the hourly task, or you can force `anacron` to run immediately by running `anacron -fnd -t $HOME/.anacron/etc/anacrontab -S $HOME/.anacron/spool/`.

Hope this helps someone else in the future!